# Floating an "ol" element

Tags: css, css-float

In [this](http://jsbin.com/ugehid/2/) demo, the `ol` shouldn't overlap at all with the `div`. Why isn't it working, and how do I fix it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't floated the ol element. If you do that, it doesn't overlap. Is that the desired result?

Comment: Great! Please mark the answer as accepted, if you so please. Also see the answer by Madmartigan, as this can be something you'd want as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can "fix" this by changing the `list-style-position`:

```
ol {
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

A value of `outside` will display the counters outside the containing block, like in your demo.

Demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/3XwsP/